# How to use random sentences as html spinner loader

Tags: javascript, html, css, spinner

I have the following code which runs perfectly fine with spinner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
       <head>
       <title> Do Something </title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/style.css"/>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" charset="utf-8">
       </head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div class='loading-text'>Processing</div>
     <img class="loading-gif" id="processing" src= "images/squares.gif"  alt="Processing" />
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Now instead of the static text "Processing". I'd like to generate
sentence picked from a repository (e.g. quote from famous author). 
How can I do that?

Comment: `var quotes = ['i am a quote', 'uwotm8?']; jQuery('.loading-text').html(quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)]);` - [Example/Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvj1dnzg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be using jQuery, so this is a vanilla javascript version: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwp4zcm2/1/

```js
var strings = [
  'For he who can wait, everything comes in time.',
    'We will wait to see if it is a doozy before we decide how to cover it, and what it all means.',
    'We need to talk about what we are going to do and see and decide. We\'ll have to wait and see.'
];

var rand = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
document.getElementById('loading-text').innerHTML = rand;
```

```css
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.loading-gif {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div id='loading-text' class='loading-text'>Processing</div>
     <img class="loading-gif" id="processing" src= "images/squares.gif"  alt="Processing" />
</div>
```

It's actually self-explanatory, but you first have an array of quotes, then pick a random one and "append" it to your inner-text element.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to put the script outside the html? e.g. `static/make_quote.js`. How can should I implement it? I tried by adding 
` <script src="static/make_quote.js"></script>` It gave me `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: Your code doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry about firefox, I didn't test with it but you can use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`. I've updated my code and it works correctly now. If you want to use it in an external file you can either append the <script> tag at the bottom of your <body> (the easiest way) or wrap all the javascript code inside a `window.onload = function() { // put the js here }`

Answer (score 2):

Heres a solution using a jokes API but you could use whatever quote API you wanted to. The fade in/out isn't perfect but you get the picture (updates every 6 seconds).

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/jakebown/pen/gaLNqe)

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=John&amp;lastName=Doe",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.loading-text').fadeOut().delay(100).text(data.value.joke).delay(100).fadeIn();
    }
  });
}, 6000);
```